# what is the difference between custom segue and modal segue

Tags: ios, segue

I am working in an iOS app ,which consists both modal segue and custom segue. In that app i hvae used API. When i am invoking API in custom segue, it works properly ie After getting the response from API ,it will present destination view controller based on the result of API.
But when i am invoking API in modal segue it doesn't work properly ie it present destination view controller before getting response from API.It causes my app getting crashed

Comment: No way to tell without seeing your code. A custom segue can be whatever (within bounds) the designer of it wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0):

A modal segue is a pre-built segue by which one View Controller can present another. A custom segue is a segue subclass that you define yourself. See [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html) for more information about building custom segues.

However, I can't tell what's crashing your app without seeing some code or more concrete information.